# How do I use Windows Firewall allow an application inbound/outbound access to ONLY a single IP?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall

How do I set up the built in windows firewall in a way that follows this logic...

Allow ALL traffic to/from [Application] to/from [IP]

Deny  all OTHER traffic to/from [Application]

.

Essentially, a whitelist of IPs, but ONLY for that specific application.

I know I could do this with a global deny + an allow for the one application. But then everything else would be denied and I can't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my idea:

Using Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security, you may create a Custom
rule pertaining to the program in question.

When you arrive in the New Rule wizard to the *Scope* section,
choose for remote IP addresses the option of "These IP addresses", click "Add...",
choose "This IP address range", and give a range of `0.0.0.1` and up to
the allowed address *minus one*. Create the rule as blocking.

Repeat this for creating another rule for this program that blocks
the address range of from the allowed address *plus one*
and up to `255.255.255.253`.

Now only that IP address should be allowed for this program.

Comment: Yeah. This is how I ended up doing it. But you got your answer in before I could get back here to answer it myself. So you get the Internet Points.